# Combined Neural network with spektral and keras

Tags: python, keras

I'm trying to build a combined model of two neural networks. The first is a graph convolutional neural network built using spektral and the second is a simple convolutional neural network taking in one hot encoding data.
The two neural networks run independently and the combined neural network is created with all the neurons. The problem comes when using the .fit method to train it on the data.

The graph neural network uses the data as input using spektral's .load() function, whereas the data from the conv neural network is simply an array.
I don't know how to give the input data so that the conv neural network can process it. I'm running out of ideas...

```py
def create_gcn_model_to_comb(inputs, channels, n_layers, dropout_rate=0.2):
    
    x = spktrl.layers.GeneralConv(channels)(inputs)

    for _ in range(1, n_layers):
        x = spktrl.layers.GeneralConv(channels)(inputs)
    x = spktrl.layers.GlobalMaxPool()(x)
    x = keras.layers.Flatten()(x)
    x = keras.layers.Dense(channels, activation='relu')(x)
    x = keras.layers.Dropout(dropout_rate)(x)
    outputs = keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)

    model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
    #compile the model
    adam = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08)
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=adam, metrics=['acc'])

    return model

def create_cnn_model_to_comb(inputs ,channels, n_layers, dropout_rate=0.2):
   # Specify input
    x = inputs

    x = keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, activation='relu')(x)
    x = keras.layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2)(x)

    for _ in range(1, n_layers):
        x = keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu')(x)
    x = keras.layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2)(x)

    x = keras.layers.Flatten()(x)
    x = keras.layers.Dense(channels, activation='relu')(x)
    x = keras.layers.Dropout(dropout_rate)(x)
    outputs = keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)

    model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
    
    #compile the model
    adam = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08)
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=adam,  metrics=['acc'])

    return model

def create_combined_model(gcn_channels, gcn_layers, cnn_channels, cnn_layers, dropout_rate=0.2):

    in_x = keras.Input(shape=(dataset[0].x.shape[1],))
    in_a = keras.Input(shape=(dataset[0].a.shape[0],), sparse=True)
    in_y = keras.Input(shape=(dataset[0].y.shape[0],))

    
    gcn_inputs =[in_x, in_a]
    gcn_model = create_gcn_model_to_comb(gcn_inputs ,gcn_channels, gcn_layers, dropout_rate)
    gcn_outputs = gcn_model.output
    
    cnn_inputs = keras.Input(shape=(174,4))
    cnn_model= create_cnn_model_to_comb(cnn_inputs, cnn_channels, cnn_layers, dropout_rate)
    cnn_outputs = cnn_model.output
    # Concatenate GCN and CNN
    combined_outputs = keras.layers.concatenate([gcn_outputs, cnn_outputs], axis=1)
    global_input = [in_x, in_a, keras.Input(shape=(174,4)) ]

    combined_outputs = keras.layers.Dense(units=64, activation='relu')(combined_outputs)
    combined_outputs = keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.2)(combined_outputs)
    combined_outputs = keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(combined_outputs)
    
    # Create combined model
    combined_model = keras.Model(inputs=[gcn_inputs, cnn_inputs], outputs=combined_outputs)
    adam = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08)
    combined_model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=adam, metrics=['acc'])

    return combined_model
```

You can find here the functions to create the models and the code when I need to give the input:

```py
X = np.array(vector_ohe)
y = np.array(labels)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

idxs = np.random.permutation(len(dataset))
split_va, split_te = int(0.8 * len(dataset)), int(0.9 * len(dataset))
idx_tr, idx_va, idx_te = np.split(idxs, [split_va, split_te])
data_tr = dataset[idx_tr]
data_va = dataset[idx_va]
data_te = dataset[idx_te]

# Data loaders
loader_tr = DisjointLoader(data_tr,batch_size=batch_size, epochs=10)
loader_va = DisjointLoader(data_va, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=10)
loader_te = DisjointLoader(data_te, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=10)

combined_model = create_combined_model(16, 3, 16, 3, dropout_rate=0.2)


# Train combined model

history = combined_model.fit(
    x= [loader_tr.load(), X_train],
    y = y_train,
    steps_per_epoch=loader_tr.steps_per_epoch,
    validation_steps=loader_va.steps_per_epoch,
    epochs=epochs,
    batch_size=batch_size
)
```

And this is the error:

```
ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: (<class 'list'> containing values of types {"<class 'tensorflow.python.data.ops.flat_map_op._FlatMapDataset'>", "<class 'numpy.ndarray'>"}), <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Thanks in advance